# Parsing Hex Dumps in Python

Tags: python, parsing, hex, byte, bit

I'm trying to parse a dump of hex data. I have a document that labels out the bit offsets, but am given 8 byte blocks of data. What's the best way to say, `Ok, I want to read in the first 8 byte block, parse the bits out and then skip over the next 16 8-byte blocks and read in and parse the next block.` Etc. Here is an example of the dump

0x0000000100000000 0x0000000000000001 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0301000009798086 0x0000100100028888 0x0000000000000100 0x0000000000000000 0x020180860002f780 0x616c756d69530003 0x2050585320646574 0x000700004d4d4944 0x0000000000000003 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0xffffffff00000000

Is it something that involves converting the hex to binary and iterating over the bits?

So far I can read in the file and split the hex blocks into their own index.

```
data_test =  "".join(["{0:04b}".format(int(c,16)) for c in str(data_test)])
```

allowed me to convert the 8 byte block of hex information into a 64 bit string representation of the data. How could I iterate through the bits and is this the most efficient way of doing so?

Comment: Hint: `int("0xff", 16) == 255`; also `"a b".split(" ") == ["a", "b"]`. Should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Do you actually want it to be bits, or do you mean each byte?

Comment: So, if I have 0x0000000100000000. The docs lay out: 63:32 is this, and 31:16 is this and 15:8 is this and 7:3 is this, 2 is this, 1 is this 0 is this. So I'd assume bits, right? So given an 8 byte block, I want to be able to parse out and write, "15:8 - Status - 0x06" basically.

Comment: Is it easier to convert it to bits if this is the format?

Comment: Why do you call `str(data_test)`? What is `print(repr(data_test))`? What is `print(repr(open('path/to/file', 'rb').read(18)))`?

Comment: '0x0000000100000000'
'0x0000000100000000'